# Getting error at the time of importing numpy library in Python 3.9

Tags: python, numpy

I am using win 64 with python 3.9 version. I have also installed numpy version 1.19.3 on my system but I'm still getting the error below.

How do I resolve this error?

```
 from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Uttam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 9, in <module>
    import glob
  File "C:\Users\Uttam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\glob.py", line 4, in <module>
    import re
  File "C:\Users\Uttam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 127, in <module>
    import functools
  File "C:\Users\Uttam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\functools.py", line 18, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "C:\Users\Uttam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from operator import eq as _eq
ImportError: cannot import name 'eq' from 'operator' (D:\Python Pro\operator.py)
```

Comment: Its not because of numpy. Maybe there is no method or class named 'eq' from ur operator module. Post ur file structure for full clarification.

Comment: Hi Surya,                            below is my program  import numpy as np
n=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print(n)

Answer (score 0):

Change your **operator.py** name in **Python Pro** folder to another name.

Because numpy also have operator.py, so it makes numpy ambiguous to get the operator.py